# Handling program args with Groovy Eclipse plugin v2

Tags: eclipse, groovy, args

I am wondering how to handle program arguments when you are running Groovy within Eclipse.  It isn't as straight forward as it is from the command line and I am having trouble figure it out.  Im using Eclipse 3.5.   My run configuration has these arguments all on one line:

```
--classpath "${workspace_loc:/GroovyProject};${workspace_loc:/GroovyProject}" 
--main groovy.ui.GroovyMain "C:\Temp\Workspace\GroovyProject\GroovyTest.groovy " 
argtest1 
argtest2 
argtest3
```

The script I am using to try to make this work looks like this:

```
// GroovyTest.groovy
class GroovyTest {      
  static main(args) {
    println "hello, world"
    for (arg in this.args ) {
      println "Argument:" + arg;
    }       
  } 
}
```

The error I get is:

```
hello, world
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: args 
for class: GroovyTest at GroovyTest.main(GroovyTest.groovy:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have az unnecessary **`this`** in the `for (arg in this.args)` line.

`this.args` means that you have an instance of the GroovyTest object and you refer to its args field. In this case args is a method parameter so you have to refer to it simply as `args`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much! I copied the hello world example from another site and so i didnt question it. So, if I extend the GroovyTest object , then I refer to the parents class args as this.args right?

Comment: @djangofan: No, the this keyword is for referring the current object (the object whose method is being called). Your static main method is a class method where this cannot be used.You can find more on the usage of this topic in http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html